# Some part of the navigation back item is not clickable iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a problem in my navigation back button, the top most is not clickable, only half(bottom) of it is clickable.

Here's the screen shot of it:

[image]

I put a border to know what is the size of the button but the only clickable part is marked with the yellow line.

I also tried doing the button manually but got the same result, here is my code:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_back.png"];
navButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
[navButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
navButton.layer.borderWidth =1.0f;
[navButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem * barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:navButton];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem;
```

EDIT:

When I remove the code (meaning I'm using the default) the clickable part becomes:

[image]

EDIT:

To make it more clear, here is the code (load view) of the parent view controller

```
-(void) loadView{
scroll_flag = 0;
webService = [[WebServiceController alloc] init];
webService.webserviceDelegate = self;

secondTabView = [[SecondTabView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
secondTabView.secondTabViewDelegate = self;
self.view = secondTabView;
isDisplayed = NO;
x=0;

[secondTabView setupLayout];
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


dictTrap = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
secondTabView.tableView.delegate = self;
secondTabView.tableView.dataSource = self;
mapView.delegate = self;
}
```

Heres the my code in pushing view controller:

```
secondTabNextController = [[SecondTabNextViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondTabNextController animated:YES];
```

And the code for the Controller that contains the Back Button

```
-(void) loadView {
secondTabNextView = [[SeconTabNextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
secondTabNextView.secondTabNextDelegate = self;
self.view = secondTabNextView;
heartVal = 0;
commentVal = 0;
[secondTabNextView setupLayout];
webService = [[WebServiceController alloc] init];
webService.webserviceDelegate = self;
dateTimeArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

secondTabNextView.contentScrollView.delegate = self;
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init] ;
self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,385,100,20);
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.hidden = YES;
[self.pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageControl];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
feedsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIButton * theView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 46)];
[self addViewToTab: loginController.tab :theView];
[theView bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:theView];

btnHeart = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnHeart setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addHeartButton:self.tabBarController :btnHeart];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:btnHeart];

btnComment = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self addCommentButton:self.tabBarController :btnComment];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:btnComment];
}
```

I already remove the code and using the default.

Comment: Your back arrows in the two examples look identical - is there any reason in particular that you're trying to override the default arrow? Or are the examples images not real screenshots?  
Can you also show us a bit more of the ViewController? What's going on beneath the navbar?  
Have you tried using the Xcode6 "Debug View Hierarchy" mode - is there anything strange happening in front or behind the navbar?

Comment: the reason why I'm trying to override the default arrow is because i get that bug. The screenshot are real, i copied the arrow of the real Nav bar arrow that's why it looks the same

Comment: Ok, then it is clearly nothing to do with your implementation of the button, because the default button is doing the same thing. You're looking in the wrong place for the solution. Leave the button as the default, and look for other issues.

Comment: can't find any issue except this code: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: it's very unusual, this is the first time i have encounter this bug.

Comment: I haven't seen it either, but it is definitely something else that you're doing - nothing to do with the implementation of the button because the default button does the same thing.
Now that we know that, it is impossible to debug this with the information you've given us.

Comment: I see.. I'll edit the questions so it would be more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63901/discussion-between-siburb-and-aldrin-equila).

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very strange way to add a new button there. I've never seem this particular problem, but I do know that you shouldn't put buttons too close to the bottom (underneath) of a navBar because the navBar "intercepts" touches, so this may be a similar issue when you just add a UIButton as a subview.

Anyway, the `UINavigationItem` has a `leftBarButtonItem` property, so why not use that?

How about something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButton:)];
```

Comment: I've tried using the default (leftBarButtonItem) but it shows me the same result.

Comment: when I resized the image, the same problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem related "ImageInsets". Create UIBarButtonItem like that.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem;
backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_back"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popBack)];

[backButtonItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, -100)];
[backButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor color]];
```

Comment: thank you for immediate reply. but I'm getting the same result. the only clickable part is half of the arrow button